# Corona SDK (LUA) timers and countdowns

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk

I have this game where a function spawns random objects every time a timer fires. It look like this:

```
function showCountDown (event)
    -- Condition to show and hide countdown
    if countDownNumber == 0 then
        spawnShit = 0
        timer.cancel( timerSpawn )
        timer.cancel(countdownTimer)
        print( 'NO MORE SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWWNS' )
    end

    if countDownNumber >= -1 then
        countDownNumber = countDownNumber -1 
        countDownText.text = countDownNumber
        spawnShit = 1
    end

    if score == nil then
        score = 0
    end

    return true
end
```

The problem is the timer somehow insists on stopping on -2 instead of on 0, which is quite frustrating. 
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Maybe you have a better method for creating a countdown timer that triggers different events(stops spawning objects, start win/lose/pause screen etc.

Also it seems like (from looking at the console during testing) that the function `showCountDown` is triggered about 3 times extra, after the spawnShit = 0, timer.cancel(myTimers) is fired, which is odd because I'm canceling the timer that triggers the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
if countDownNumber >= -1 then
    countDownNumber = countDownNumber - 1
```

This means that the `if` block will be entered whenever `countDownNumber` is larger or equal to -1, i.e. any positive number, 0, and -1. Inside the block, it gets decreased by 1 so the last value will be -2.

You probably want `>= 1`, which will make its last value 0:

```
if countDownNumber >= 1 then
        countDownNumber = countDownNumber -1
```

Comment: Well simpel. I just figured if i sat i to be larger or equal to -1 or 0 it would work, but setting it to 1 worked like a charm!